# running 64-bit application with 32-bit shared object

Tags: 64-bit, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I have 64-bit Linux OS, and would like to ask if I can use the following combinations:

1. 64-bit application (java) using 32-bit shared object (C++) on 64 bit OS
2. 32-bit application (java) using  32-bit shared object (C++) on 64 bit OS
3. 64-bit application (java) using 64-bit shared object (C++) on 64 bit OS

Thank you,
Ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix 32 and 64 bit code in the same process. So option 1 is out but the other two are fine.